# python FSM Fysom callbacks on the other way

Tags: python, fsm

I am using Fysom to create FSM.
I want to use callbacks in an other way:

```
TABLE = {
'initial': 'OFF',
'events': [{'name': 'load', 'src': 'OFF', 'dst': 'LOADED'},],
'callbacks': {'onload': myfunction,}}

fsm = Fysom(TABLE)
```

Here if I launch `fsm.onload()` it will execute `myfunction`. Instead I want If I launch `myfunction()` it will lunch `fsm.onload()`.

I took a look on the script and related part is here:

```
def _enter_state(self, e):
    '''
        Executes the callback for onenter_state_ or on_state_.
    '''
    for fnname in ['onenter' + e.dst, 'on' + e.dst]:
        if hasattr(self, fnname):
            return getattr(self, fnname)(e)
```

I don't see how to change this peace of code for my purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot implement callbacks "in the other direction" without touching `myfunction`.
A callback is actually an inverted call ([hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle)), so the inverse of a callback is a simple call.

What this means is that `myfunction` should call the state machine transition directly. As a consequence, the state machine object must be in the scope of `myfunction`.

At this point you have some possibilities for implementation :

- Have `myfunction` be a closure :

  ```
  def outer():
      fsm = Fysom(TABLE)
      def myfunction():
          print("I call the state machine transition when called")
          fsm.onload()
      return fsm
  ```
- Use a global state machine or scope it in a class :

  ```
  class Foo(object):

      def __init__(self):
          self.fsm = Fysom(TABLE)

      def my_method(self):
          self.fsm.onload()
  ```
- Create a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) that calls the state transition method before/after executing the function. Then decorate away with

  ```
  fsm = Fysom(TABLE)

  @transition(fsm, "onload")
  def myfunction():
      pass
  ```

  Note that this also requires `fsm` to be defined in this scope.

Comment: First thanks' for help. I am using the 2nd point but actually I don't want to call it in my_method (that's the reason of my question). What I want is to define all function/method which will launch `self.fsm.onload()` (automatically) when called. And I want to define it in `TABLE`. As you said I cannot implement it without changing `myfunction`. Maybe I can if I change something in constructor (__init__) of class Foo and link between Foo and Fysom ?
3rd point: To my mind the decorator is exactly the same thing as calling it into the function.

Comment: I don't see a way to do that right now. The fysom could probably rewrite the code of `myfunction` so that it calls `onload`, but that would be really messy.

Maybe you can put a list of method names in `TABLE`, and then use `getattr`/`setattr` in the class constructor to replace the methods? That would look a lot like the decorated version, as you mentioned.

Comment: Ok so I finally choose the decorated version. It's easier because I don't really see how to implement with getattr/setattr version. Thank you for help.